# Анимация кнопки после привязки обработчика события tkintter python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, windows-7

Делаю на tkinter (python3) простенький GUI. Ставлю кнопку `Button`, привязываю к ней обработчик события `button.bind('<Button-1>', eventHandler)`. Всё работает, однако возникает следующий эффект: пока обработчик не привязан, (нет соответствующей строчки кода), при нажатии на кнопку ЛКМ она "утапливается" (т.е. видна соответствующая анимация). После привязки обработчика по нажатию на кнопку обработчик срабатывает, однако сама кнопка внешнего вида не меняет (т.е. анимации "утапливания" нет, она статична). Как можно и фунцию-обработчик вызвать, и анимацию проиграть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из вариантов сделать вручную: в обработчике события `eventHandler`:

```
def eventHandler(event):
    event.widget.config(relief = 'SUNKEN')
```

Прописать изменение рельефа. Однако если всё оставить так, то кнопка останется утопленной после нажатия. Соответственно надо дополнительно прописать изменение рельефа после отпускания ЛКМ.